# I need to know what is this beautiful font

Tags: fonts

I would love to use this font, it really looks great but I have no idea which one it is.
Could someone guess which font is used to write this [article](http://cosy.informatik.uni-bremen.de/sites/default/files/security_franis_paper.pdf) ? Any help is precious for me.

Comment: The body text is set in Garamond (you can get this information from the PDF properties).

Comment: The article contains lots of fonts.  The font of the main text looks much like Garamond (capital W is a good point of reference); however, there are many sub-types of Garamond.  `pdffonts` says "GaramondBE-Regular"...

Comment: I tried GaramondBE-Regularbut by calling `\usepackage{ebgaramond}` but the result is not the same :(